# Can't use the extended User model

Tags: django

I want to add a department field on my User model. I am using sql server as my db. I did the following in models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Employee'
```

Then, using stored procedure I can fill all the fields of User easily, but when I want to fill the extra field department, I get the error

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /fetched

User has no employee.
```

in views.py, where I retrieve the data from procedure:

```
q = User(id=result_set[i][0], username=result_set[i][1], is_staff=False,
                 first_name=result_set[i][4], last_name=result_set[i][3], email=result_set[i][8])
        q.set_password(result_set[i][2])
        q.employee.department = 'something'
        q.save()
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that such constructed (and even not yet saved) `User`, has no `Employee`.

Comment: U mean that I am refering to the model too early?

Comment: well, so now I save the query before trying to add user.employee.department field, but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the AbstractUser to your model 

In models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class Employee(AbstractUser):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```